# Encounter Run-time error '1004' when using trying to access a range within a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel VBA project. I want to change the interior colour of a range of cells within a named range [Named "Mawe" & M, where M is  a user input integer]. This is how my code looks like.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FB 2015")

If HomeScore > AwayScore + 1.5 Then
sht.Range("Mawe" & M).Range(Cells(C + 1 - x, 1), Cells(C + 1 - x, 4)).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 231, 255)
ElseIf AwayScore > HomeScore + 1.5 Then
sht.Range("Mawe" & M).Range(Cells(C + 1 - x, 1), Cells(C + 1 - x, 4)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 223, 223)
```

When i compile my code, i encounter Run-time error '1004'. I have no idea what is the issue I am facing.

P.s. Not sure if this info is useful. My code is written under the sheet where my ActiveX control command button is placed instead of in a module. In my codes, i need to refer to ranges in different sheets under the same workbook.

Comment: You need to use address strings, rather than range objects, if the ranges are relative to the original range.

Comment: Try putting the parentage to the `Cells` ; `sht.Range("Mawe" & M).RAnge(sht.Range("Mawe" & M).Cells(C + 1 - x, 1),sht.Range("Mawe" & M).Cells(C + 1 - x, 4))...`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to solve the problem with the following code:                                                                                          sht.Range("Mawe" & M).Range(**sht**.Cells(C + 1 - x, 1), **sht**.Cells(C + 1 - x, 4)).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 231, 255)